# Javascript Canvas drawing out of order?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am attempting do draw some text over a rectangle, however the text is for some reason being drawn before the rectangle. This doesn't seem to happen when I use another shape such as an arc and happens in both Chromium and Firefox so I don't think it's a browser issue, this is my code:

```
map_context.fillStyle = "#95609F";
map_context.rect(32,32,192,192);
map_context.fill();

map_context.fillStyle = "white";
map_context.fillText("+", 128, 128);
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace these two lines:

```
map_context.rect(32,32,192,192);
map_context.fill();
```

with just:

```
map_context.fillRect(32,32,192,192);
```

You probably run this same code in a loop to draw several images but forget to clear the path each time. For paths (such as rect() adds to) you need to use `beginPath()`, so an optional approach would be:

```
map_context.beginPath();
map_context.rect(32,32,192,192);
map_context.fill();
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me looking in the right direction, I was doing something similar to the code I posted somewhere else in my program and that was leading to it manifesting in the place I was working on. Using the beginPath() approach in both places fixed it.